# How to fix `operator cannot be applied to type` in Rust?

Tags: rust, websocket, tauri

If I have a msg with the `?` operator it shows me this error:
`operator cannot be applied to type`

And when I remove the `?` operator from the msg it shows me these errors:
`method not found` and `expected enum Message, found reference`

How can this problem be solved?

I've added the exact errors that the compiler shows in the comments in the code:

```rust
let (mut ws_remote, _) = connect_async(request).await?;
let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4444").await.expect("Can't listen");

while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
  let mut ws_local = accept_async(stream).await.expect("Failed to accept");

    let handle_one = task::spawn(async move {
      while let Some(msg) = &ws_remote.next().await {
        let msg = msg?;
//|               ^^^^ the `?` operator cannot be applied to type `&Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>`
        if msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary() {
//|            ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>`
          &ws_local.send(msg).await;
//|                      ^^^ expected enum `Message`, found reference
        }
      };
      Ok(())
      // Result::<(), tungstenite::Error>::Ok(())
    });
    
    let handle_two = task::spawn(async move {
      while let Some(msg) = ws_local.next().await {
        let msg = msg?;
        if msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary() {
          ws_remote.send(msg).await;
        }
      };
      Ok(())
      // Result::<(), tungstenite::Error>::Ok(())
    });

    handle_one.await.expect("The task being joined has panicked");
    handle_two.await.expect("The task being joined has panicked");
  }
```

Comment: Remove the `&` in `&ws_remote.next().await`.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for answer!  But now I have this errors: `move occurs because "ws_remote" has type "WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::MaybeTlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>>, which does not implement the "Copy"` and `value used here after move` How to fix it?

Comment: I'd need to see full compiler output and code that I can compile myself to investigate further.

Comment: Ah, the problem is that you use `ws_remote` in _two_ `async move` blocks. You have one value and you're trying to give ownership of that to two different futures; that can't work.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm posted a full code in answer. 
"You have one value and you're trying to give ownership of that to two different futures; that can't work" - How can I fix it?

Comment: Fundamentally, I'm not sure you can with this exact type, because sending and receiving both require an exclusive reference; you can't do both at the same time. Usually send+receive types like this have some way to split off the sending half and the receiving half, but I'm not seeing that here.

Comment: @cdhowie Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: @cdhowie I'm split `ws_local` into `write_local and read_local` and `ws_remote` into `write_remote and read_remote`, I'm updated my answer with split, but I got error "value moved here, in previous iteration of loop"

Comment: The question as originally posed is solved by my answer; if you now have a different problem, consider creating a new question -- however, _please_ include the ___full compiler output___ in your question, and (ideally) a ___self-contained example___ that I can compile myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the WebSocket client from two different concurrent futures.  This is fundamentally impossible with a single combined Stream and Sink because both operations require an exclusive reference.

However, the `futures` crate provides a [`split()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.21/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.split) extension method, which splits the combined Stream and Sink into a separate Stream and Sink value; then you just move each half into the appropriate `async` block.